# How to penalize False Negatives more than False Positives

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

From the business perspective, false negatives lead to about tenfold higher costs (real money) than false positives. Given my standard binary classification models (logit, random forest, etc.), how can I incorporate this into my model?

Do I have to change (weight) the loss function in favor of the 'preferred' error (FP) ? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Many algorithms in scikit-learn support a `class_weight` param which can be used to set the weights of the class.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for your comment. I know that option and used it before. Even rather extreme weights like `{0:.01, 1: .99}` do not create major shifts that reflect my business related cost ratio. That's why I'm looking for a way to change sth. else. Any further idea?

Comment: *"From the business perspective, false negatives lead to about tenfold higher cost than false positives"*: this is clearly opinion and business based, don't make it a general claim, as it isn't.

Comment: @ivegotaquestion you could also tune your cross validation towards recall, using a [recall_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html) or [make_scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html). I added an answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55478131/2456179)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several options for you:

- As suggested in the comments, `class_weight` should boost the loss function towards the preferred class. This option is supported by various estimators, including [`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html),
  [`sklearn.svm.SVC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), [`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), and others. Note there's no theoretical limit to the weight ratio, so even if 1 to 100 isn't strong enough for you, you can go on with 1 to 500, etc.
- You can also select the decision threshold very low during the cross-validation to pick the model that gives highest recall (though possibly low precision). The recall close to `1.0` effectively means `false_negatives` close to `0.0`, which is what to want. For that, use [`sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) and [`sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) functions:

  ```
  y_scores = cross_val_predict(classifier, x_train, y_train, cv=3,
                               method="decision_function")

  precisions, recalls, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_train, y_scores)
  ```

  If you plot the `precisions`  and `recalls` against the `thresholds`, you should see the picture like this:

  [image: precision-recall-tradeoff]

  After picking the best threshold, you can use the raw scores from `classifier.decision_function()` method for your final classification.

Finally, try not to over-optimize your classifier, because you can easily end up with a trivial const classifier (which is obviously never wrong, but is useless).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the `decision_function` part? How exactly do you interpret it?

Comment: Also how did you manage to plot threshold against the precision/recall? The size of the threshold list is one less than precision/recall lists.

Answer (score 7):

As @Maxim mentioned, there are 2 stages to make this kind of tuning: in the model training stage (like custom weights) and the prediction stage (like lowering the decision threshold).

Another tuning for the model-training stage is [using a recall scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter). you can use it in your grid-search cross-validation ([GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)) for tuning your classifier with the best hyper-param towards high recall.

GridSearchCV **scoring** parameter can either accepts the **'recall'** string or the function [**recall_score**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html).

Since you're using a binary classification, both options should work out of the box, and call **recall_score** with its default values that suits a binary classification:

- average: 'binary' (i.e. one simple recall value)
- pos_label: 1 (like numpy's True value)

Should you need to custom it, you can wrap an existing scorer, or a custom one, with [**make_scorer**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html), and pass it to the **scoring** parameter.

For example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, make_scorer

recall_custom_scorer = make_scorer(
    lambda y, y_pred, **kwargs: recall_score(y, y_pred, pos_label='yes')[1]
)

GridSearchCV(estimator=est, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=recall_custom_scorer, ...)
```

Comment: Could you please explain how `recall_custom_scorer` takes into account the 10:1 cost ratio (or how it could)?

Comment: Not directly but by tunning your cross validation process towards recall (the OP wanted to penalize false-negatives for binary classification models). I suggested using the grid-search cross-validation object (GridSearchCV) with a recall custom scorer (see code above). This will tune the classifier with the best hyper-params towards high recall (i.e. less false-negatives). Hope this helps :)